# How do you make a container fit its contents perfectly without forcing the contents to shrink to their min-width?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div with a fluid width (for example, min-width 200px and max-width 1000px). We'll call this div Div1. I want to wrap this div in a parent div and I want this parent div to shrink to fit Div1 without affecting Div1's width at all.

From what I've read, the way to get a parent to fit its contents is to set the parent's display to inline-block. However, whenever I do this it seems to force the contents to shrink to their min-width. Here's an example on codepen - I have two divs with the exact same properties but one of them is forced to its min width because it is has a parent container with display: inline-block.

http://codepen.io/ahung89/pen/LGqrwz

Code below (HTML on top CSS on bottom)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-with-min-width">
    This div is forced to its minimum width.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div-with-min-width">
  This div is not forced to its minimum width.
</div>

.div-with-min-width {
  border: 1px red solid;
  background: red;
  color: yellow;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.container {
  border: 4px green solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

How do I make the parent wrap to the child's width without actually changing the child's width?

Comment: It seems what you're looking to do is have the child compute its width based on the containing block above the parent (which could be for example the grandparent element), rather than the containing block belonging to the parent itself, then have the parent fit the child based on that width. I'm just thinking aloud here - someone else might have a solution based on my interpretation.

Comment: (If all you're looking to do is add an additional border, you could cheat using the outline property on the child, but outlines don't affect layout which could be a dealbreaker for you.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually do want the parent container to fit its child exactly. My use case: the inner element is a table with a fluid width. I want to have a button below the table that is always perfectly aligned with the table's right edge. My thinking was that I'd have a parent container that fits the table perfectly and then have the button in the footer float to the right of the parent container. There might be a better way to do this, but it made me curious about how to shrinkwrap a fluid-width element.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` or `float: right;` or `overflow: hidden;` to collapse the parent element.